# Value from a dropdown does not get passed to a php script in $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have created a form with a dropdown that is populated from a mysql database. The dropdown is populated correctly with all the names, and when the form is submitted, $_POST shows there is a variable with the name in the array, but there is no value, and all other elements of the form submit correctly. This is the code I have for the form

```
    <form action ="returns.php" method="post">

    Name:<br><?php

        $sql= "SELECT Fund_name FROM fundnames";
        $fnames=$connect->query($sql);

        echo "<select name='fund'>";
        while ($row = $fnames->fetch_array())   {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['Fund_Name'] . '">' . $row['Fund_name'] . '</option>';

        }
        echo "</select>";

    ?></select>

    <br>Date:<br><input type="text" name="date" id="date"><br>

    Return: <br><input type = "text" name = "return">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I test the output in the target script with

```
<?php 

print_r($_POST);?>
```

The result that appears is

```
Array ( [fund] => [date] => 09/07/2018 [return] => 4 )
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging to figure out the source of the problem. You have some PHP. Which generates some HTML. Which is used to create an HTTP request. Which runs some PHP. Which gives an unexpected result. Where does the problem start? Is the HTML being generated wrong? Then look at the first PHP script and the generated HTML while forgetting about the result in the second PHP script. Is the HTML fine? Then look at *that* and the PHP while forgetting about the first PHP script.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky — That isn't the value of `[fund]`. That is the next two keys and their associated values.

Comment: have a look at the select html. Can you see the values echoed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worth a shot:

Replace

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['Fund_Name'] . '">' . $row['Fund_name'] . '</option>';
```

with

```
echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['Fund_name']) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Fund_name']) . '</option>';
```

That will at least ensure that the `<option>` tags have valid html.
But standardising the case of `Fund_name` is probably the thing that will fix your problem.

Notice that your original code uses `$row['Fund_Name']` as the value and `$row['Fund_name']` as the label. My guess is that only one of these is set, so the value is always null (which would probably generate warnings, but maybe you have those suppressed)

Comment: Adding    htmlspecialchars fixed it thanks very much!

Comment: No problem. A useful habit is to use your browser's dev tools to inspect the html, or view the source, to check for things like this.